# How to fluidize sand inside a 55gal Steel Barrel?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics

Looking for recommendations on how to make a fluidized sand bed inside of a 55 gal steel barrel. I've seen many examples of it done with pipes but I am worried about the evenness of the fluidization. The best looking solution I have seen is a video where they use a pressure chamber and a piece of cloth streched out (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odl6NK0FDnY) but again I am not sure if I can follow it exactly since the barrel will have about 500-600lbs of sand.

This is the closest solution I can think of but definitely open to other ideas:

[image]

Comment: So how much air will you need to move?

Comment: That's what I'm not sure about, I'm not too familiar with fluid mechanics. I figure it may behave something like inlet_air_pressure = air_volume * sand_resistance. And at some air volume the sand becomes fluidized but I'm not exactly sure what that is.

I'm thinking the only way to solve it is trial and error but I want make sure the bottom of the barrel can both support the weight of the sand and also provide minimal resistance for the air flow.